# Twitter bootstrap form fields too small

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I know this topic "sounds" a lot like others that are out there but I've looked through all the existing threads (well "most" anyway) and I still have a problem I could use help on ...

The *problem* is not too dissimilar to what others have described:

- Certain FORM elements do not display their full vertical height
- Most notable amongst these is the INPUT type looks sort of anaemic in size when sitting next to a button or "add-on" class
- More recently I noticed an even more severe problem ... radio buttons become "radio dots" as they are so small they're hardly visible.

Now a LOT of people solved their problem by making sure they specified the **DOCTYPE** correctly at the top of their HTML document. I too found that this simple adjustment did the trick on my static HTML mock-up. Sadly when I switched to Wordpress the problem reappeared and yet I am very definitely putting the HTML 5 DOCTYPE signature at the very top of the output (I've checked this several times with "view source" as I thought maybe I'd lost my mind).

I've included a quick snapshot of the screen in case this helps shed any light on this. You can find it here: http://www.flickr.com/photos/14261777@N00/6957941282/. Note the tiny little dots at the bottom that are supposed to be radio buttons. More obvious are the INPUT fields that are not tall enough. Oh, and also for completeness, here's a screenshot of how my HTML source starts: http://www.flickr.com/photos/14261777@N00/6957952802/.

I'd love to hear from anyone who has a theory on WHY this could be happening and any workarounds that might exist (even if the source of the solution is unknown). I have tried imposing CSS attributes like line-height, height, min-height, etc. and a few others with zero effect.

Comment: I would imagine that one of your theme css files is doing this. WordPress will shove a ton of extra CSS files into your document.

Comment: You can use google chrome's web inspector to see what css rules are affecting an element and remove those css files... but it's pretty obvious those elements are affected by other css files on top of bootstrap.css

Comment: You must be overwriting the bootstrap styles somewhere, if you post your site we can take a look.

Comment: I've included a screen shot (http://www.flickr.com/photos/14261777@N00/7105215597/) of Chrome's debugger through the "computed style" format so that it's easy to see the hierarchy/cascade of stylesheets. I've expanded height and line-height to illustrate that bootstrap.css is the predominate enforcer of style here and the values are reasonable (aka, don't indicate the problem I'm having).

Comment: This also is showing "background-color" because I explicitly over-wrote it myself because on top of the problems described above the background of most widgets was greyed out. In this case I was able to override the effect with CSS whereas changing the height properties has no effect on the primary problem I'm discussing here.

Comment: Finally, I'm not trying to be sneaky by not posting the actual files but it's all in a development environment that isn't publicly accessible. If there are any other screen shots that I can post to give information I'm more than happy to and eventually this will get into a more visible area but I'm really hoping to solve it before then.

Comment: I believe -- but don't know -- that this is something MORE than just a CSS issue. In order to eliminate CSS though, can someone point me to the variables which would effect the height of INPUT and Radio buttons? I'll manually override these and see if I can use CSS to force it to work. I have a sneaking feeling that this will not work but I'm not a CSS expert.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have two problems.  The `input type=text` problem and the `radio` button problem.  Without seeing your code, it appears as though your textbox problem is related to `DOCTYPE` and your radio button problem is related to overriding CSS styles (can confirm if you post the inspector output for the radio buttons).

If your variables are showing as the correct values (eg. 18px height), which they are, then it is most definitely a `DOCTYPE` issue.

From [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) on A List Apart:

> You’ve done all the right stuff, but your site doesn’t look or work as
> it should in the latest browsers.
>
> You’ve written valid XHTML and CSS. You’ve used the W3C standard
> Document Object Model (DOM) to manipulate dynamic page elements. Yet,
> in browsers designed to support these very standards, your site is
> failing. A faulty DOCTYPE is likely to blame.
>
> This little article will provide you with DOCTYPEs that work, and explain the practical,
> real–world effect of these seemingly abstract tags.

Here's the recommended list of DOCTYPEs as per W3C:

http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: Terry, thanks for your suggestions. WRT to DOCTYPE ... it did/does feel like a DOCTYPE-like problem but as you can see in screenshot ( http://www.flickr.com/photos/14261777@N00/6957952802/ ) that I am definitely putting in a valid HTML5 DOCTYPE and in the right place. My only thought is ... does Wordpress put Content-type like message in the HTTP header (which is not visible in view source). Could this create an override in the DOCTYPE setting in the HTTP body?

Comment: Can you inspect the *rendered* HTML (not view source, but live inspection like you were doing with the CSS)?  If so, look at what DOCTYPE is rendered.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that i've now made some progress but not the type that solves the problem ... I have found this CSS block ( http://www.flickr.com/photos/14261777@N00/7105644417/in/photostream ) that is causing a lot of the problems. Specifically the "padding" and "border" settings. I can override them in Chrome's debugger and get something reasonably close to what it should be. I figured I could just override these properties in my child theme but when I try things get worse. I'm still trying to "describe" what happens when I do this.

Comment: I think you're over-complicating it dude.  The CSS works.  You need to find what is creating a malformed DOM on *your* site.

Comment: Terry, i think you gave me the kick i needed. Instead of placing blame on mystical unexplained stuff it was just a case of needing to dig into piles of CSS. I have solved it now. In some cases I'm still not completely sure how the cascade ended up as it was but it works.

Comment: Terry, thanks, your comment put me on the right track.  I had <!DOCTYPE HTML> but I had put in some debug echos which were outputting characters before the doctype tag, so the browser was ignoring the doctype. I took out the debug echos and voila! everything went back to how it should be, so the doctype tag must be the first thing output otherwise it gets ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's interested, here's what I added to fix the problem:

```
input, input[type="text"], input[type="radio"], isindex, .uneditable-input {
    padding: 4px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #CCC;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-left-color: #CCC;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #CCC; 
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #CCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.input-append .add-on, .input-append .btn {
    margin-left: -6px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
        -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
}
```