# Bootstrap: Elements too small on mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to make all html elements in `bootstrap` like inputs, buttons, text and the nav-bar bigger when the page is displayed on a smartphone? Because it isn't really `responsive`, if all elements are so tiny that it is hard to touch them.

Comment: seems this question has some of the answers you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272965/twitter-bootstrap-form-fields-too-small?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap font scaling too small on mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746811/bootstrap-font-scaling-too-small-on-mobile)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Has been addressed at [Bootstrap font scaling too small on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746811/bootstrap-font-scaling-too-small-on-mobile) .

Possibly, you need to add the `viewport` meta tag to your `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: wow, this single line solved my problem, wasted a lot of time searching for a solution, thank you

Comment: just have to comment to say THANK YOU!